# How to make a leaderboard in unity using the result JSON of Firebase database

Tags: json, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, leaderboard

I am using unity3d and Firebase.
I can send data to the database, and I can receive it, but I don't know how to use it in the project.
I need to transform this json file into an array that has name and score, but I can't get it :(

```
{
    "Elisa" : {
      "name" : "Elisa",
      "score" : "53"
    },
    "Javi" : {
      "name" : "Javi",
      "score" : "12"
    },
    "Jon" : {
      "name" : "Jon",
      "score" : "33"
    }
}
```

And I using this class

```
[Serializable]
public class Points
{
    public string name;
    public string score;



    public Points(string _name, string _score)
    {
        this.name = _name;
        this.score = _score;
    }
}
```

If you want to look at my code, it's this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;
using System;

public class DatabaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    DatabaseReference reference;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Set this before calling into the realtime database.
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://project-SecretCode.firebaseio.com/");

        // Get the root reference location of the database.
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

    }

    public void ButtonLoad()
    {

        ReadDataBase();
    }
    //leee toda lavase de daton en el apartado score
    [ContextMenu("ReadDataBase")]
    void ReadDataBase()
    {
        //reference
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
       .GetReference("Score")
       // .GetReference("Score").Child("javi")

       .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                // Handle the error...
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                //Debug.Log(snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());

                string jsonStr = snapshot.GetRawJsonValue(); //result Json To String
                Debug.Log(jsonStr);
            }
        });


    }
}
[Serializable]
public class Points
{
    public string name;
    public string score;



    public Points(string _name, string _score)
    {
        this.name = _name;
        this.score = _score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert from Json string to Unity object using [`JsonUtility.FromJson<T>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html):

So adding something similar to this function:

```
public static Points FromJSON(string jsonString)
{
    return JsonUtility.FromJson<Points>(jsonString);
}
```

---

1. Seems like you will need to add a class for holding the array, as in your code it holds for one player:

```
class PointsArray {
    Points[] allPlayerPoints;
}
```

2. Your json currently is a dictionary with key:value, needs to have `[` `]` for it to be an array. (and then you don't duplicate the name):

```
{
    [
        {
          "name" : "Elisa",
          "score" : "53"
        },
        {
          "name" : "Javi",
          "score" : "12"
        },
        {
          "name" : "Jon",
          "score" : "33"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I don't know how to make it have another format.
52/5000
base fire creates the database with this format: [Image](https://ibb.co/rcSdf24)